# Escaping string in less and passing variables

Tags: css, less

By using Less I need to escape a string which  LESS doesn’t recognize.

```
filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#26ffffff, endColorstr=#24ffffff)";
```

At the same time I need to pass two variables startColor and endColor to this string

```
.get-ARGB(@startColor, @endColor){
    /* ARGB backgrounds for IE 7+8 (black background with 50% transparancy) */
    filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=@startColor, endColorstr=@endColor)";
}
```

Any ideas how can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use string interpolation:

```
   filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=@{startColor}, endColorstr=@{endColor})";
```

Comment: This Wiki page on GitHub explains it also well:
https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Escaping